# Passing data to clients via a server

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop a simple solution that will allow me to pass data from 2 clients to eachother, via a server.

I'm very new to Java so this is quite tricky for me. What I currently have is a constructor that sets up a connection to the server, and the server will reply when the connection is successful (this works at the moment).

My application is a GUI program, so I thought my best bet would be to place the connection into paintComponent as there is a timer attached to this, so was hoping that each tick of the timer would send data to the server, however this just crashes the program.

What would be the best way to -

- Send data from client to server
- Catch data on server
- Send data from server to another client

This is my objective ultimatly.

My code is very basic, I really dont know what my next step is -

Client -

```
Socket clientSocket = null;
  DataOutputStream os = null;
  BufferedReader is = null;

  String request;
  String responseLine;
  String data;

  try {
     clientSocket = new Socket("LocalHost", 5000);
     os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
     is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Dont know host name!");
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldnt get I/O for connection");
     }

  if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
     try {
        request = "Hello Server \n";
        os.writeBytes(request);
        System.out.println("Client: " + request);

        if((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null){
           System.out.println("SERVER: " + responseLine);
        }
        //os.close();
        //is.close();
        //clientSocket.close();
     }   
     catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
     }
   }
```

Server -

```
ServerSocket service = null;
  Socket server = null;

  BufferedReader is;
  DataOutputStream os;

  String line;

  try {
     service = new ServerSocket(5000, 2);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
    }

  try {
     server = service.accept();
     is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
     os = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

     if( (line = is.readLine()) != null) {
     String text = is.toString();
     System.out.println("Data: " + text);
     }
     os.close();
     is.close();
     server.close();
  }
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't assigned anything to `request`.
2. If you have, outside the the code you have posted, it doesn't contain a line terminator, so you are reading lines but not writing lines.
3. You are mixing streams with readers and writers.
4. You are catching exceptions and then proceeding as though they hadn't happened. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that same `try` block.